# jQuery: How add JavaScript alerts based on ":contains(…)", if the text is temporary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to change a `h1` if a specific `div` gets clicked. I have already coded this, and it works fine. **But:** Now, I want to add specific on-click alerts for every **headline**.

I tried it like this:

```js
// This works:

let myText = "Hello"

$("#one").on("click touchstart", function() {
  myText = "One";
  $("h1").text("One");
  return false;
});

$("#two").on("click touchstart", function() {
  myText = "Two";
  $("h1").text("Two");
  return false;
});

$("body").on("click touchstart", function() {
  myText = "Hello"
  $("h1").text(myText);
});


// This works not:

$("h1:contains('Hello')").click(function() {
  alert("Hello. Some text.");
});

$("h1:contains('One')").click(function() {
  alert("Here is text to One.");
});

$("h1:contains('Two')").click(function() {
  alert("Two is very cool.");
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: default;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello</h1>

<div id="one">Click me</div>
<div id="two">Click me</div>
```

**For example:** If you click the green box, and then the headline that contains a "One", there should be an alert.

I have tried it with `:contains(…)`, but unfortunately, it does not work.

Would be veeeery thankful for help! <3

And yes, this complexity is necessary, because there will be many other functions integrated in the end.

Comment: If all you want to achieve here is alerting of different texts - then why try and add three different event handlers in the first place? Add _one_, and inside the handler function, check what the text content currently is, and alert your matching text accordingly.

Comment: @Wimanicesir – The alert boxes should contain some additional information and should only get visible if you click on a headline.

Comment: "_And yes, this complexity is necessary, because there will be many other functions integrated in the end._" When having already a complicated code for a couple of functions, the complexity won't decrease with more functions. You're building a maintain nightmare. If you've more than one element involved with your event, you should not use `id`s at all. Instead, make a well-structured markup, group the elements with classes, and use a JS model of the data/process, and event delegation. That way you can build a page which doesn't need any updates to JS when the content of the page is updated.

Comment: You'd need [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/qcxsfvgn/). No matter how many divs you added or removed from the wrapper, the script works without any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a switch case to split up your functionality.

```js
// This works:

let myText = "Hello"

$("#one").on("click touchstart", function() {
  myText = "One";
  $("h1").text("One");
  return false;
});

$("#two").on("click touchstart", function() {
  myText = "Two";
  $("h1").text("Two");
  return false;
});

$("body").on("click touchstart", function() {
  myText = "Hello"
  $("h1").text(myText);
});

// If you want to split up functionality
$("h1").click(function() {
  switch($(this).html()) {
  case 'One':
     alert("Here is text to One.");
    break;
  case 'Two':
    alert("Two is very cool.");
    break;
  case 'Hello':
    alert("Hello. Some text.");
    break;
  default:
    // code block
} 
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: default;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hello</h1>

<div id="one">Click me</div>
<div id="two">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's interesting! But in the alert boxes should be different texts in the end. I am going to edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hey Anna, I made an edit so you can split up the functionality based of the text with a switch case. Is this the result you wanted?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Please add "event.stopPropagation()" to "H1" click to stop on click from "body".

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event based on the matching text at the time the script is run.  You could remove and reattach each time one of the other elements is clicked.

```
<script>
    const rebind = () => {
        $("h1").off("click touchstart");

        $("h1:contains('Hello')").click(function () {
            alert("Hello");
        });

        $("h1:contains('One')").click(function () {
            alert("One");
        });

        $("h1:contains('Two')").click(function () {
            alert("Two");
        });
    }
    rebind();
    let myText = "Hello"

    $("#one").on("click touchstart", function () {
        myText = "One";
        $("h1").text("One");
        rebind();
        return false;
    });

    $("#two").on("click touchstart", function () {
        myText = "Two";
        $("h1").text("Two");
        rebind();
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click touchstart", function () {
        myText = "Hello"
        $("h1").text(myText);
        rebind();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: The multiple click events are not best practice. Don't advise bad practices..